# Redirecting serial ports with multiple instances of socat

Tags: networking, redirect

I have multiple serial device servers for a home automation system. I need to be able to create multiple (5 or 6) virtual com ports. I am guessing there is a way to do this with socat but so far I haven't figured it out or found any examples.

The command below works well but only for one virtual port. As a test, I've tried creating multiple instances using different terminals and the second instance fails.

```
socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/ttyV00,raw,echo=0 tcp:192.168.0.16:9100
```

Ideally I can have another instance linking to ttyV01 for a different ip. Something like

```
socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/ttyV02,raw,echo=0 tcp:192.168.12.85:5200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching I found some examples [here](https://forums.homeseer.com/showthread.php?t=177869&highlight=socat) at the Homeseer website.

From what I have learned you can add the & to the end of the socat command and it will run the socat in the background. I believe it is the way Ubuntu evaluates commands using the && ; and &.

Here are the 2 commands that are currently redirecting 2 virtual pty ports to different IP address and running in the background successfully.

```
sudo socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyV00,mode=777,echo=0,ignoreeof,b115200,raw TCP:192.168.0.16:9100 &

sudo socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyV01,mode=777,echo=0,ignoreeof,b115200,raw TCP:192.168.0.85:5002 &
```